# Ruby 2.0.0 and git collision

Tags: ruby, git

I am at a loss here. I use GIT by opening up a DOS window, which launches Ruby 2.0.0.
When I do a GIT diff, it gives me a blurb, but then leaves me in some sort of editing limbo with the prompt saying (END) instead of c:... (see screenshot)

I've tried Ctrl^C and :q and a bunch of other things but I cannot seem to escape this mode.
In the screenshot you can see that I typed Ctrl^C and it LOOKS like I've escaped back to the Cmd prompt, but the moment I try to type anything else, it puts me back in the (END) mode.

I do not understand what I've done to get in this mode, or what I do to escape it.

[image: screenshot:]

Comment: "a bunch of other things" is not very helpful. Have you tried using Ctrl+D? That signals the end of input.

Comment: How is Ruby coming into the picture?  Your prompts look like normal Windows command-line prompts.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a suggestion - you might be more comfortable using a git GUI client.  Both sourcetree and tortoisegit are free, and a google search can undoubtedly churn up other choices for you.

Comment: 'a bunch of other things' I'm kind of floundering here, so nothing specific, uh, ESC, Ctrl-Q, etc. 

Tried your Ctrl-D. Did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `git diff` drops you into a pager such as `less` or `more`.  Control-C may not break you out of the pager, but you should be able to just hit `q` to quit.   You can use `git --no-pager diff` so it doesn't use a pager at all.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something, or someone, changed your ~/.gitconfig file. That can override a lot of standard git behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

q seems to have worked - THIS time.

It was naturally one of the first things I tried, but it was not working. Don't know what I was doing wrong, but it's working now. (Perhaps I will return if/when it stops working again.)

Comment: You should probably accept the answer that solves this problem.  @infused does indeed describe what is going on here with the pager, as you have found.  Your current "answer" is really more in the form of a comment, and probably isn't as helpful in its current form, as the referenced answer.

Comment: I did post this as an 'answer your own question'.
StackOverflow does a very good job of making a confusing conversation interface.